# Cleaning column using regex remove character based on conditions

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-re

I am trying to figure out how I would deal with the following situation:

I have raw data that has been manual input and several unnecessary characters and i need to clean the column.

Anything after a symbol such as (-,/,!,#) should be removed if less than 5 letters.

**Raw data**

NYC USA - LND UK

GBKTG-U

DUB AE-      EUUSA

USA -TY

SG !S

CNZOS !C SEA

GAGAX"T

AEU DGR# UK,GBR

**Desired Output**

LND UK

GBKTG

EUUSA

USA

SG

CNZOS

GAGAZ

UK GBR

Comment: This is unclear to me "Anything that is less than 5 letters"? Can you elaborate more? For example: in "NYC USA - LND UK", "NYC USA"  is not less than 5 letters but you removed in your output, why?

Comment: @uguros Hi, the column sometimes has the origin and the destination and i only need the destination. So that is why i need to remove NYC USA. Sometimes a person has just random symbols and letters with no meaning Eg GAGAX"T need to be GAGAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each line between `origin` and `destination` using the regex groups adjusting the `separator` (`[^\w\s]`) as needed. Next, count the number of letter on the right side of the separator symbols cheking for stated number of letters.

**Details:**

- `(.*?)` : capture group - zero or more characters (except line ending) non-greddy
- `[^\w\s]` : follow by any character that is *not* a letter, digit, underline ([a-z-A-Z0-9_]) or space
- `(.*)` : capture group - zero or more characters (except line ending)

File *sample.txt* used as input

```
NYC USA - LND UK
GBKTG-U
DUB AE- EUUSA
USA -TY
SG !S
CNZOS !C SEA
GAGAX"T
AEU DGR# UK,GBR
```

```py
import re

f = open("sample.txt", "r")
txt = f.read()

dest = []
r = re.findall(r"(.*?)[^\w\s](.*)", txt)
for f in r:
    if sum([i.isalpha() for i in f[1]]) >= 5:
        dest.append(f[1].strip())
    else:
        dest.append(f[0].strip())

print(dest)
```

```py
['LND UK', 'GBKTG', 'EUUSA', 'USA', 'SG', 'CNZOS', 'GAGAX', 'UK,GBR']
```